# Recursive design in NoSQL

Tags: database, nosql

**How could I express the following design?**

- There are two entities: user and group
- Group can have users and other groups
- User can't have other users or groups
- Efficiently query **any** group and everything it contains
- There are conceptually no depth limits (current hardware dictates it, *e.g* 5 for query speed)

Examples:

[image]

---

I need to use NoSQL and also be able to cache this data (Redis for example, which is NoSQL itself).

### ---

My current idea:

Every group is a single unit and only contains children (users and groups) **IDs**. Then I query all the children by IDs. If some of these also have children, I'll make another roundtrip and so on and on..

As you can imagine, this solution requires multiple queries and the amount increases with every "level of deepness". The good news is that I query all these items by ID which should be extremely fast.

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: I think you should look in graph type nosql instead of key-value

Comment: you should probably store the ids of it's parent in a comma delimited string, so you have a means to track it back to its rootnode.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a graph database as they are very powerful when dealing with this kind of queries.

Bear in mind that you won't be able to query the "parents" of a node though.

You could use Neo4j for this. They have a community edition that is free. https://neo4j.com/